# Maintaining previously selected item state in stepper

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working with a Material UI stepper wherein each step returns a list of selected items.

In each step, the user can click an item that is highlighted before moving onto the next step.

The results are mapped in a separate component.

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(undefined);

const selectStyleAndFilter = (item, index) => {
        setClicked(index);
        selectedItems[activeStep] = item;
    };

    const handleBack = () => {
        setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);
        setClicked(undefined);

        if (activeStep === 1) {
            nextStep(selectedItems).then(products => {
                console.log(
                    'productCount back',
                    products.data.data.contents.total
                );
                setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);
                setClicked(undefined);
                setProductCount(
                    products.data.data.contents.total === undefined
                );
            });
        }
    };
```

However, when I click the back button to return to the previous step, the item is no longer highlighted.

I tried using the logic from `selectStyleAndFilter` in the `handleBack` function to keep the item in state:

```
   const handleBack = (item, index) => {
        setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);
        setClicked(index);
        selectedItems[activeStep] = item;
```

How can I keep the `setClicked` state of the previous item applied in the `handleBack` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `clicked` to be an object that holds the clicked item for each `activeStep`.

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState({});
```

The current clicked is derived from the `clicked` object and `activeState`

```
const currentClicked = clicked[activeStep];
```

When you set the currently clicked item, store it under the `activeSet`, and maintain the state of the other clicked items:

```
const selectStyleAndFilter = (item, index) => {
  // add the current, but maintain the state of the others
  setClicked(c => ({ ...c, [activeStep]: index }));
  selectedItems[activeStep] = item;
};
```

Don't reset the clicked state when moving between steps:

```
const handleBack = () => {
  setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);

  if (activeStep === 1) {
    nextStep(selectedItems).then(products => {
      console.log(
        'productCount back',
        products.data.data.contents.total
      );
      setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);
      setProductCount(
        products.data.data.contents.total === undefined
      );
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, The only thing I'm not sure about in your answer is what to do with the ```currentClicked``` function.

Comment: `currentClicked` is not a function, it's the clicked item for the current `activeStep`. Use it wherever you used `clicked` before.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Replacing ```clicked``` and passing the props through the mapped component did the trick.